# Why does this code using variable arguments give a TypeError?

Tags: python, function, variadic-functions

Why am i getting this an error in this code?

```
def fun(a,*b):   
    print(a,b)
fun(1,x=4,y=5)
```

when the code is executed I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: fun() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x'
```

Comment: Because your function doesn't accept optional keyword arguments. I guess, you wanted to put 2 asterisks before `b` in the function's signature.

Comment: You probably meant to write `def fun(a, **b):`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function doesn't take keyword arguments at all, only positional arguments. The `*varargs` syntax only captures extra positional arguments (without a `name=` prefix).

Either drop the keyword argument syntax and pass in positional arguments only, *or* update your function to take keyword arguments too.

The following works:

```
fun(1, 4, 5)  # b will be set to (4, 5)
```

or add `**c` or a similar keyword `**varkwargs` name to the function signature:

```
def fun(a, *b, **c):
    print(a, b, c)

fun(1, x=4, y=5)  # prints 1 () {'x': 4, 'y': 5}
```

For this specific example, the `*b` argument could be dropped since you don't actually pass in more than one positional argument here.